# Mac stuck at boot after installing Big Sur 11.3

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, startup, big-sur

I just tried installing Big Sur 11.3 from Catalina, on a 2020 Macbook Pro.

Here’s what I tried so far:

- Installed Big Sur via Software Update, everything went like normal until progress bar reached 90%
- After 4 hrs, progress bar still stuck at 90% with black screen and Apple logo
- Force shutdown then turn on again
- Login screen showed up in a Big Sur UI
- Entered password, proceeds to the same black screen and still stuck at 90% progress bar
- Waited for an hour, so I forced restart again
- Booted to recovery mode (cmd+R) and ran First Aid on all volumes, then containers, then disk (as per Apple support page)
- Restarted, still stuck at 90% progress bar
- Booted to recovery mode again and reinstalled Big Sur
- Left it to install overnight, again still stuck at 90%
- Repeated all steps above (normal restart, restart to recovery + first aid) but same thing
- Reset NVRAM
- Booted to Safe mode

On safe mode, after logging in with my user password, it asked me to create a new macOS user (along with the language, terms, apple ID etc like when setting up a brand new Mac).

I went ahead and setup a new user, safe mode booted successfully with a working Big Sur macOS. My old files were still intact when I checked the original user’s directory using the terminal (since currently in safe mode all folders are empty since it’s a new user.)

So in summary:

- Big Sur upgrade (from Catalina) didn’t complete properly
- I am able to safe boot to Big Sur but only with a newly created user
- It might be a startup issue on my original user

Any suggestions on what I should do next? My last resort would be to backup my files on an external HD using the safe boot, then do a fresh install, wiping my disk.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: Currently trying out internet recovery mode to downgrade and reinstall Catalina.

EDIT 2: When trying to reinstall Catalina, there are no available disks to choose from when it asks me where to install macOS.

Comment: When you boot on the "broken" user in verbose mode (cmd+v) can you get information?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I have exactly the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I am having the same problem. I understand that it could be related to third-party software, but I couldn’t find the cause yet.